# mod_pagespeed not found error combine_css

Tags: linux, apache, centos, mod-pagespeed

I'm getting not found error for combine_css

Below is my apache config:

```
ModPagespeedMapRewriteDomain domain.com.au 10.3.12.2
```

This seems to work sometimes but not all the time and it keeps on creating file that is not found occasionally.

Whenever this happens, I have to do below:

```
touch /var/cache/mod_pagespeed/cache.flush
```

Is there a reason why this is happening?

Comment: Can you explain why you are rewriting from a fixed IP address to domain.com.au? That seems odd.

Comment: @sligocki I have multiple domains under same IP address on same server

Comment: You can run multiple domains from the same IP address with default config. Why did you add this directive? It is very strange to use an IP address in this directive.